# jquery changing src attribute end

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so I'm trying to have a toggle switch between two images. One an animated gif and the other a jpg. Basically, the client wants a ton of these animated gifs of the functionality of his product, but I want to add a switch to turn it on and off because it gets really busy. So, I was wondering if I had all of the images with a class, could I just set a toggle to change the last three characters of all the images from gif to jpg because all the rest of the src will be different.

This obviously won't work, but I'm hoping you can follow the logic.

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
if () //If the image ends in .jpg
{
     //Somehow strip the attribute of .jpg
     //Somehow append the attribute to add .gif 
} else {
    //Somehow stip the attribute of .gif
    //Somehow append the attribute to add .jpg
}
});​
```

Any suggestions? Another option would be nice, too if my logic is stupid. I'm kind of new to this. I tried a few different things, but couldn't manage to figure out.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? [javascript determine end of string](https://www.google.ie/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+determine+end+of+string&oq=javascript+determine+end+of+string&gs_l=hp.3..33i29l2.320632.327824.5.328031.35.33.0.0.0.7.273.2943.27j5j1.33.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.9ivRY0tVWHI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms&fp=b4a5795965c8af13&bpcl=40096503&biw=1221&bih=669) -1 as I don't think the question shows any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this operation for all images here it is.

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
    ( ".imgClass" ).each( function( ) {

        var src = $(this).prop( "src" );

        if( /\.jpg$/i.test( src ) ) {
            $(this).prop( "src", src.replace( /\.jpg$/, ".gif" ) );
        } else {
            $(this).prop( "src", src.replace( /\.gif$/, ".jpg" ) );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this on is a bit better. I didn't realize at first that the last one didn't toggle all images. I made it toggle all but they would all come back with the same source.

Answer (score 3):

We could grab the last three or four characters from the images *src string* and compare it.

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
    var ending = this.src.slice( -3 );

    switch( ending ) {
       case 'jpg': 
           this.src = this.src.replace( /jpg$/, 'gif' );
           break;
       case 'gif': 
           this.src = this.src.replace( /gif$/, 'jpg' );
           break;
    }
});
```

I used a `switch/case` just in case there might be further formats in the future.

Another option is to use jQuerys `.toggle()` method in a way like

```
$('img.img-toggle').toggle(function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace( /jpg$/, 'gif' );
}, function() {
    this.src = this.src.replace( /gif$/, 'jpg' );
});
```

`.toggle()` will automatically switch between the two functions you need to provide.

Comment: I would search for `/jpe?g$/` instead, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    var src = $img.prop('src');
    if (src.match(/\.jpg$/)) {
        $img.prop('src', src.replace(/\.jpg$/, '.gif'));
    } else {
        $img.prop('src', src.replace(/\.gif$/, '.jpg'));
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8NR5H/)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do something like this...

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    if (src.indexOf(".jpg") != -1) //If the image ends in .jpg
    {
        src = src.replace(".jpg", ".gif");
    } else {
        src = src.replace(".gif", ".jpg");
    }
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

Comment: That ain't working for `<img src="/images/test.jpg.gif" />` and `<img src="/images/test.gif.jpg" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: Yep, like most of the suggestions on this page.  Everyone's assuming sensible image names.

Comment: This was perfect. The only thing I changed was $(this) to $('img.img-toggle') so it affected all of the images on the page. That was more of a personal preference thing though. Thank you very much.

Comment: `src.indexOf('anything')` will completely ignore *where* in the source string a match is found. Also, you shouldn't recall the jQuery constructor just to get and set the `src attribute`.

Comment: Like I said above, it's assuming sensible image names.  If someone wants to call an image `myimage.jpg.gif` then they're obviously not going to like this solution.  There's only 1 answer on this page (as of writing) that covers this eventuality, and that's @jAndy's answer.  No-one else's does.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are a lot of `img.img-toggle` elements in the page, you better use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/),
than event listening on each single element.

With event delegation you register a single event listener on a shared parent; this is usually sensibily
better than registering a ton of different listeners.

jQuery supports event delegation.

```
$("#a_common_ancestor").on("click", "img.img-toogle", handler);
```

With this in mind let's now write the login inside the `handler` function.

```
function handler () {
  // `this` refers to the element that was clicked;
  // it is an image, so it has an `src` attribute.
  this.src = this.src.replace(/\.(jpg|gif)$/, function (_, capture1) {
    return capture1 === "jpg"
      ? ".gif"
      : ".jpg";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.img-toggle').click(function() {
    src = $(this).attr('src');
    if (src.substr(src.length - 4) == ".jpg") //If the image ends in .jpg
    {
        src = src.replace(".jpg", ".gif");
    } else {
        src = src.replace(".gif", ".jpg");
    }
});​
```